# scipy.misc save image with transparency

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to load a image, turn some of the pixels into transparent by setting the alpha param in scipy.misc module, e.g.:

```
import scipy.misc as sm
im = sm.imread("tmp.png", mode = "RGBA")
im[0, 0, :] = [0,0,0,0]
```

When I try to save it:

```
sm.imsave("out.png", im)
```

The RGB setting for that pixel have been changed (to black in this case), but  the transparency setting does not manifest. How could I fix this?

Comment: *"... but the transparency setting does not manifest."*  What does that mean?  How do you know?  If you read back `"out.png"` with `im2 = sm.imread('out.png')`, what is `im2[0,0]`?

Comment: Hi, I thought  if I open up the saved picture with an image viewer, I should see pixel (0, 0) to disappear. Instead pixel (0, 0) just turned black. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works. I just wasn't aware the jpg format does not support transparency, if you save the image in png then things work.